# How to simplify addition of quotients with variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quotient-group

Recently I was given a problem where I had a quotient with variables and a regular quotient and had to simplify it, but had no clue how to do it. For example,
$$  \left|\frac{x-1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{5}\right|=\frac{4}{5}\left|\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right|$$

Can you please explain how this works?
I am having trouble understanding this, any help will be appreciated.
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM6Sw.jpg)

Comment: Get a common denominator, which is $5(x+3)$. Multiply the top and bottom of $\frac{x-1}{x+3}$ by $5$, and multiply the top and bottom of $\frac{1}{5}$ by $x+3$.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick indicates in the comment, you do this with variables the exact same way you do it without variables. Remember that variables are just place-holders for numbers (or whatever else they are varying over). They behave just like those numbers.

There is one rule for mixing multiplication/division with addition/subtraction. That is the distributive law:

$$A(B + C) = AB + AC$$

To apply this to adding fractions, you need to rewrite them into a form where it applies. If you have $$\frac ab + \frac cd$$
you don't have a common multiplier. But, you can rewrite the fractions in a form where they do. Note that $\frac AA = 1$ and multiplying by $1$ does not change values. So you can multiply the first term by $\frac dd$ and the second term by $\frac bb$:
$$\begin{align}\frac ab + \frac cd &= \frac dd\frac ab + \frac bb\frac cd \\&= \frac{ad}{bd} + \frac{bc}{bd} \\&= \frac 1{bd}ad +\frac 1{bd}bc \\&= \frac{1}{bd}(ad + bc) \\&= \frac{ad+bc}{bd}\end{align}$$

In your example, $a = x-1, b = x+3, c = -1, d = 5$
$$\begin{align}\frac{x-1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{5} &= \frac 55 \frac{x-1}{x+3} + \frac{x+3}{x+3}\frac{-1}5\\
&=\frac{5x-5}{5x+15} + \frac{-x-3}{5x+15}\\
&=\frac 1{5x+15}\left((5x-5) + (-x - 3)\right)\\
&=\frac {4x-8}{5x+15}\end{align}$$

That combines the fractions, but then your calculation goes a step further, factoring the combined fraction:
$$\frac {4x-8}{5x+15} = \frac{4(x-2)}{5(x+3)} = \frac 45\frac{x-2}{x+3}$$

And finally also handles the absolute values:
$$\left|\frac{x-1}{x+3}-\frac15\right|=\left|\frac45\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right| = \frac45\left|\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right|$$

Of course, one normally does not write out the steps as I've done here - particularly in pulling out the denominators as a multiplication by the inverse. I choose to show it this way to tie it directly to the distributive law, so that you can see how this is justified.